# Disable Chrome XSS protection for automated testing

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, cucumber, xss, watir

I have a ruby sinatra web application which I am using Watir-Webdriver and cucumber to test it. I want to test that one of my forms isn't vulnerable to XSS attacks. I have written a automated test for this which fails because my chrome browser is blocking the attack. If I run it in Firefox it work perfectly.

Is there a way to disable this XSS protection on the fly in chrome?

Changing to firefox is not something I want to do.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `X-XSS-Protection: 0` in your response header to tell Chrome to disable its XSS protection:

```
get '/xxxx' do
  headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '0'
  #...
end
```